# Upgrading Cassandra db schema in Production

Tags: cassandra, production

The query is about most common problem that we face today in distributed cloud environment.

We design cassandra schema (version, v1) before implementing application and will use the same schema to query(or used)from application(version, v1). 
Now, when the application need to be enhanced, how to handle multiple problems that araise without stopping(outage) the service to the end-user.

1. Assume app1 with three instances using db with three cluster nodes as backend.
2. Enhanced app and db schema by adding new column and removed one column. Since app should always be Highly available, one of the app instance receives data and queries db with deleted column which may result in column family mismatch.

Queries:
Does blocking the service and redeploying all the apps with new version is the only solution?

How to Handle db upgrade in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preform the deployment in 2 stages. First deploy v2 which requires a new column and stops using the column meant to be deleted. Once v2 has been deployed on all hosts, the unnecessary column can be safely dropped.